# How to set the DataGrid's DataSource from outside?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am developing a control in WPF, my control contains some other WPF controls such as labels, buttons and one DataGrid. So, what I have been trying to do is to create a dependency property that allows me to get the DataSource for my dataGrid from the outside of my container control.

So far I have this code:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty dataSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                                            "DataSource",
                                                                            typeof(object),
                                                                            typeof(MyCustomControl));
    public object DataSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (object)GetValue(dataSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(dataSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

But what I cant figure out is where I have to write this code:

```
    myDataGrid.ItemsSource = DataSource;
```

I mean, what I need is, in my xaml file, be able to do this:

```
<MyCustomControl Name="MyControl" DataSource={Binding MyData}/>
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The children of a WPF control inherit its DataContext, so unless I'm missing something, simply setting your DataGrid's `ItemsSource = "{Binding}"` in XAML should result in it binding to `MyData`...

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but since I am totally new in WPF, could you post you answer with some example please? I'd appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours of research I've found the solution to my problem:

Since I needed to have access to a nested control dependency property from the container control I did this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty itemsSourceProperty = ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty.AddOwner(
                                                                        typeof(MyCustomControl), 
                                                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                                                                            ItemsSourcePropertyChangedCallback));

    public System.Collections.IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get
        { return (System.Collections.IEnumerable)GetValue(itemsSourceProperty); }

        set
        { SetValue(itemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void ItemsSourcePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject controlInstance, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        MyCustomControlraceUIGridControlInstance = (MyCustomControl)controlInstance;  
        raceUIGridControlInstance.extendedDataGrid.ItemsSource = (System.Collections.IEnumerable)args.NewValue;            
    }
```

After doing that you can write in you XAML:

```
<MyCustomControl Name=mycustomControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourData}" />
```

You can do this with any nested control dependency property.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the datacontext of the current form has a property MyData, you just need the following:

```
<MyCustomControl Name="MyControl" DataContext={Binding MyData}/>
```

and in your custom control, you can bind to MyData with:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource = "{Binding}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply, but, What If I need to add in my container control more properties as following: `<MyCustomControl Name="MyControl" DataContext={Binding firstData} AnotherPorperty={Binding secondData}/>`. How could my inner dataGrid know what data to take?